# How to stop Ubuntu processes to stop fan from making noise?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, cpu, power-management

I am using an UBUNTU OS on my ASUS G75VW machine but the fan noise is not pleasant at all.

It affects my meetings and kills my quietness: I'd like an advice on how to stop this probably by killing background processes or some other better approach.

Comment: How old is your machine? I fixed my fan noise by clearing out the dust of ages, and refreshing the thermal paste on the CPU chip. The processes heat it up, but the aircon cools it down.

Comment: 2013 is when I got it. Do I need a technician to clear out the dust

Comment: I'd say yes. Simply unscrewing the screws in a wrong order can break it. Or watch a bunch of videos on how to do it before.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Mine was about that age, and the fan airways were about 80% blocked. An office with aircon might be a lot cleaner than my home office, though. The screws can be very hidden (e.g. in recesses under the feet) and you may need to unplug and remove the DVD and HDD to get at the case. I found a YouTube for my specific model, and I built my own ZX80 from a kit way back, so I managed. But any doubts, have the experts do it.

Comment: Yeah awesome madvice

Comment: This really sounds like a hardware issue regarding excessive fan noise. I'd suggest you have a trained technician look a the system and see about replacing the noisy fan--it is either starting to fail or an older non-quiet fan.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the number of running processes: The fan noise is due to the temperature of the CPU. If you have several, or even just one really hungry process, your fan is going to turn like a mad.

If you don't guess what's eating your process power:
check with `top` or `htop` on the command line, these tools will list first the most hungry processes. (check the CPU% numbers)

In critical situtation, where my computer is choking, I might even use `kill`, or `killall` so as to stop these culprit processes.

Becareful though to know what the processes are all about. If you don't understand their name... Get some info first. Do this often, and with time you will have a better vision of what going on.

---

On Ubuntu also, I was used to removing the graphical effects from the GUI. That reduced power consumption VERY MUCH. You might even consider using alternative window managers that will consume less energy: think fluxbox, xmonad, awesome. There are tons of them. But that needs you to learn much more, and change your habits. (I advise you also to think of it in the long term, this way you can fit your linux closer to what you want, and feel like at home on your computer)

You can dim the light of your screen: I use `xbacklight`, and set screen luminosity to something like 5 or 10%. Even 3% could be sufficient in dim/shady environment. 20% and 30% can usually be ok for my daily needs, if I'm not too close from a window or external light.

---

In meeting, if you only need to takes notes: log off, kill the xserver, and use only vim (or your terminal text editor of choice: `nano`, `emacs`, `kakoune`) in the tty.

So as to switch to the tty, press ctrl alt + F1-F6  (there are six of them).
Ctrl alt F7 will switch you back to the screen reserved for xserver, in case it is running. (You have to restart it if you have killed it when you decided to work only in the tty).

---

These trics work the same so as to prolong the battery time, if you are short on power. In the train for example, I might very well switch to the tty only, if I only need to work on text notes, or code.